# How to fix the border around the navbar transition?

Tags: html, css

I made a navbar transition with a circle that expands as soon as the hamburger is clicked, i can see a thin line of background at the top and left border.

```
nav {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    border: solid 3px white;
    height: 5vh;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    display: flex;
}

.nav-links {
    position: fixed;
    background: black;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    flex-direction: column;
    clip-path: circle(100px at -15% -15%);
    -webkit-clip-path: circle(100px at -15% -15%);
    transition: all 1s ease-out;
    pointer-events: all;
}

.nav-links.open {
    clip-path: circle(1500px at -15% -15%);
    -webkit-clip-path: circle(1500px at -15% -15%);
}
```

Comment: Anti-aliasing / sub-pixel rendering would be the most likely issue,

Comment: Could you post all the code necessary to reproduce the problem? Otherwise, it's difficult for us to help you.

Comment: I understand, but its already a lot of code. Anyway i have found what causes the issue. It's in the CSS .nav the border. If i get right of the border the transition is fine

Comment: I added margin -3px to .nav-links and the border problem is solved now